# Product image did not render when sharing link of product on Twitter first time

Tags: twitter, share-open-graph

The product share on **Twitter** for the first time not render the product image.

I have set the `<meta>` tag with og:image value.
But twitter not show this image first time.

I have code below meta tags.

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content='summary_large_image'>
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.example.org/image.jpg">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="200" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="200" />
```

Comment: the mistake is here `content="https://www.example.org/image.jpg` this  is not a right url, right? you need to give your own url , where the image actually located like `<meta property="og:image" content="https://ogp.me/logo.png">` this is a real image url

Comment: @sta Yes you are correct I am supplying the correct URL in the code with "https://www.mysite-name.com/myimage.jpg"

Comment: Then I think, you may be secured by hotlink protection, do you check it with `<meta property="og:image" content="https://ogp.me/logo.png">` and then test it here  https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator

Comment: Same code render the product on the Facebook share link first time.

Comment: validate the link here and let know the output https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator

Comment: Twitter is not the same as Facebook, check the Twitter card validator.

Comment: @sta "validate the link here and let know the output" checked and image as well its link display properly.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding something like this:

```
<meta name="twitter:image" content="http://euro-travel-example.com/thumbnail.jpg">
```

More details here: https://css-tricks.com/essential-meta-tags-social-media/

Also, you can use this to preview your twitter card: https://www.bannerbear.com/tools/twitter-card-preview-tool/